# Firing a google analytics event on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to add analytics event tracking to an onclick event for a submit input on a form.

I've tried multiple different examples and referenced a couple of different SO posts to get to this point. I'm able to get the onclick to either submit the form OR fire the tracking event but not both.

**First example:** (Submits form + logs to console but doesn't fire event)

```
<!-- Analytics tracking code -->

<form action="test.php" id="form" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <!-- Submits form + logs to console but doesn't fire event -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="
        var _this = this; 
        _gaq.push(
            ['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Home Contact'], 
            function() {
                console.log('submitting'); 
                $(_this).parents('form').submit();
            }
        );
    ">

</form>
```

**Second example:** (Fires event + logs to console but doesn't submit form)

```
<!-- Analytics tracking code -->

<form action="test.php" id="form" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <!-- Fires event + logs to console but doesn't submit form -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="
        var _this = this;
        _gaq.push(['_set','hitCallback',function(){
            console.log('submitting');
            $(_this).parents('form').submit();
        }]);
        _gaq.push(
            ['_trackEvent','My category','My action']
        );
        return !window._gaq;
    ">

</form>
```

I've also found that if I add return false to the end of the first example's onclick event it will fire the analytics event tracking but not submit the form.

Answer (score 7):

(This really needs to be a FAQ...)

Google Analytics records data by requesting an image from the analytics servers, with the tracking data as parameters on the image request. If a new page is rendered in the current window immediately after a `_trackEvent` or `_pageView`, the image request can be canceled, and no data recorded.

The usual pattern is to add a small delay before loading a new page or submitting a form.

Try

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="
  var _this = this; 
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Home Contact']);
  setTimeout(function() {$(_this).parents('form').submit()}, 150);
  return false;"
>
```

My preference is bind to the jQuery submit event on the form itself, like

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Home Contact']);
  var form = this;
  setTimeout(function(){ form.submit()}, 150);
});
```

Comment: I modified this to have a 1 sec timeout + added a missing [ in the analytics push code. The event tracking worked but the form was not submitted.

Comment: Sorry about the typo's (and missing delay on setTimeout!) -- only a short delay is needed, 150ms seems to work. I also added an alternative example.

Comment: I still can't get this to work, both of these will fire the analytics event but neither will submit the form. I can't help but feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the new analytics.js (universal analytics).

Links:

- [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback%20documentation)
- A question on Stack Overflow: [google analytics send event callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760595/google-analytics-send-event-callback-function)