# Google Analytics send event callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to send an event to Google Analytics after a user is registered and **before** he's redirected.
I'm using Google Tag Manager and universal js.

First, I was trying to use the **dataLayer** object, as described here: [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/DataLayer)

Here's what my function looked like:

```
//Registering new user via ajax
$.ajax('/register/', {
    success: function() {

        //Pushing event to dataLayer
        dataLayer.push({
            'Category': 'Registration Process',
            'event': 'Registration Submit Btn'
        });

        //Logging in new user and redirecting the page with a timeout
        setTimeout(function(){
            loginAction();
        }, 500)
    }
})
```

The trouble is that I was receiving just about 25% of all events, **all others are lost**. I don't know if and when events are actually sent to Google after adding objects to the dataLayer, and I think 75% of events were not send at all.

Now I'm trying to implement another approach:

```
//Registering new user via ajax
$.ajax('/register/', {
    success: function() {

        //Sending event through ga('send')
        parent.ga('send', 'event', 'Registration Process', 'Registration Submit Btn');

        //Logging in new user and redirecting the page with a timeout
        setTimeout(function(){
            loginAction();
        }, 500)
    }
})
```

But `ga('send')` does not have any callback function again!

**How do I make sure that an event was actually sent to Google, using the dataLayer or `ga('send')?`**

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147065/google-analytics-async-events-tracking-callback

Comment: there is old tracker, I'm using universal analytics, there is no _gaq function

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally got it. It's pretty complicated and not described in docs.
In my case I use Google Tag Manager, so there some workarounds I had to make to get successfully fire an event and get callback.

First, we have to get [ClientId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId), which is required with any event sent to Google servers. Actually it's kept in cookies, but Google does not recommend to take it directly from there.

Here is how Google recommends to get it, but this **will not work** if you are using Google Tag Manager.

```
 ga(function(tracker) {
       var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
 });
```

Instead, you have to get ClientId from getAll method.

```
 var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
```

After, you have to create new tracker

```
    ga('create', 'UA-XXX-YYY', {
        'clientId': clientId
    });
```

And after that we can send an event:

```
 ga('send', 'event', {
   'eventCategory': 'YOUR Category Name', //required
   'eventAction': 'YOUR Action name', //required
   'eventLabel': 'YOUR Label',
   'eventValue': 1,
   'hitCallback': function() {
       console.log('Sent!!');
      //callback function
    },
   'hitCallbackFail' : function () {
      console.log("Unable to send Google Analytics data");
      //callback function
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI, it doesn't seem like `hitCallbackFail` exists, at least anymore?

Comment: not sure - we had to move to server side sending, because js sending is not reliable and looses data

Comment: Thanks Saved my day too!

Answer (score 6):

From Google Analytic doc
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback[News](http://note.taable.com)

```
// Alerts the user when a hit is sent.
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'hitCallback': function() {
    alert('hit sent');
  }
});
```

You can edit the `hitCallback` function for yours.

OR

```
// Use a timeout to ensure the execution of critical application code.
ga('send', 'pageview', {'hitCallback': criticalCode});
setTimeout(criticalCode, 2000);

// Only run the critical code once.
var alreadyCalled = false;
function criticalCode() {
  if (alreadyCalled) return;
  alreadyCalled = true;

  // Run critical code here...
}
```

Here you can define your function (`criticalCode`) in the above example that can ensure the data sent to Google Analytic and then work with your code.

For much understanding api of analytic, fyr: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference

Comment: This is a great bit of code to allow a custom timeout.  Never assume google is online :)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-new-page',
  'hitCallback': function() {
  alert('analytics.js done sending data');
}
});
```

In this example, the field name object configures both the page parameter, as well as setting the hitCallback. Once the tracker has completed sending data, an alert box will be shown to the user.

You can use hitCallback for events, page views etc..

Comment: does not fire...I guess, it's because I'm using Google Tag Manager