# Make sure Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics is done before redirect

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a link to my webpage where I want the user to be tracked using Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager before I redirect the user to an external page.

I want to make sure GA and GTM are done before I do the redirect. What's the best approach?

A simple approach is using a setTimeout. But is 1000ms too long or too short? Would prefer if it was possible to do redirect when tracking is actually finished?. Is GTM and GA tracking done before document ready? If not can this be forced?

```
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- ANALYTICS CODE -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- TAG MANAGER CODE -->

<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.replace("http://externalwebsite.com");
        },1000);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the GTM bucket I have Twitter and a Facebook remarketing tag.

UPDATED SOLUTION

I've updated my solution. Since I'm mostly interested in making sure GA absolutely fires before redirect this will work better.

```
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        var redirect = function(waitFor) {
            return function(signal) {
                waitFor[signal] = 1;
                for (var s in waitFor) if (waitFor[s] == 0) return;
                _redirect();
            }
        }({timeout:0,ga:0});

        var redirected = false;
        var _redirect = function () {
            if (!redirected) {
                redirected = true;
                window.location.replace("http://@Model");
            }
        };

        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-47608023-1', 'tessin.se');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'hitCallback': function () {
                redirect("ga");
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

@Html.Include("google-tagmanager-redirect.html")

<script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { redirect("timeout"); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () { _redirect(); }, 3000);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know about GTM. But for GA, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23766246/413337. It uses the *hitCallback* option to specify a function that is called when the Google Analytics event has been successfully sent.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use transport=beacon field in GA? It should guarantee delivery

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is probably to do the redirection from within GTM.

Create a custom HTML tag with the redirection code. Then use [tag](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/understanding-tag-sequencing-in-google-tag-manager/) [sequencing](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6238868?hl=en&ref_topic=3281056&vid=1-635772280837559911-2135761512) to trigger the redirection tag, that way you make sure GA is triggered before the redirect.

Comment: Cool. Any source on this?

Comment: I linked the docs for tag sequencing and an article by Simon Ahava (he's pretty much the go-to guy for anything GTM related). Tag sequencing is a rather  new feature, I don't think there is much more info.

Comment: Ok, missed that it was two links. This makes GTM too complicated to be useful in my case. Easier to move Twitter and Facebook tags to the page.

Answer (score 3):

When pushing to dataLayer with GTM you can use the eventCallback property.

```
dataLayer.push({
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'event' : 'fireTags',
    'eventCallback' : function() {
        alert('ALL tags which fire on {{event}} equals fireTags have now fired');
    }
});
```

More info: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/hitcallback-eventcallback/

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to set the 'transport' flag, either directly in your GA code or by setting the field in GTM.

More info about that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport. Note that GTM v2 still allows for the 'useBeacon' flag, but it is deprecated and if you code directly in GA, then you should use 'transport' instead.

For example, if directly coding in this flag:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'download-me', {transport: 'beacon'});
```

or in GTM:

[image]

This flag ensures that the hit is sent before the page navigates away.

Comment: Could you explain "before the page navigates away"? Would this beacon:true tag block the redirection code until it loads completely even if the redirect code is separately written at the bottom of </body> tag on the page?

Answer (score 1):

In reference to [Eike's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32439536/871150) answer. I created the following workflow to get this working;

In my code I add to the `dataLayer`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'gtm_redirect_url',
        'gtm_redirect_url': '<?php echo $url; ?>'
    });
</script>
```

In this case I'm using `PHP` to change the redirect url based on certain conditions.

Then in GTM I set up a variable called `gtm_redirect_url`

[image]

And a trigger also called `gtm_redirect_url`;

[image]

And a tag to fire the JS in an HTML snippet

[image]

All pretty simple to set up and does ensure GTM has loaded before the redirect. This method also makes it easy to add the redirect data layer tag to any page you wish.