# Form with GET action does not redirect page (relative paths?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, forms

I am trying to follow the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link), on how to make an input field act like a link.

I have setup the form, and setup the URL.

Yet, when I click the input fields, nothing happens. It does not redirect me, and there is no console errors.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

**Rendered source**:

```
 <form action="/ads/edit" style="display:inline;" method="get">
                <input onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Frontpage_Top_SaleBtn', 'click'])" type="button" class="button_green_big" value="Sælg virksomhed" />
            </form>
            <form action="/ads/editbuy" style="display:inline;" method="get">
                <input onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Frontpage_Top_BuyBtn', 'click'])" type="button" class="button_green_big" value="Køb virksomhed" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            </form>
```

**My ASP.NET MVC code that renders this**:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Edit","Ads")" style="display:inline;" method="get">
                <input onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Frontpage_Top_SaleBtn', 'click'])" type="button" class="button_green_big" value="Sælg virksomhed" />
            </form>
            <form action="@Url.Action("EditBuy","Ads")" style="display:inline;" method="get">
                <input onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Frontpage_Top_BuyBtn', 'click'])" type="button" class="button_green_big" value="Køb virksomhed" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing a google analytics event on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498046/firing-a-google-analytics-event-on-form-submit)

Comment: The link worked - thanks. I would suggest maybe keeping this one open, so Googlers can find the answer. You don't think "oh it's Google analytics" right of the hook..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted in one of the answers to the question on which you are referring

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

Set your inputs type to 'submit' instead of 'button'